# PostgreSQL- Group by without using group by in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, return, procedure

I have the following code which returns a table, but as you see it lacks the "group by" clause.

That's because, under a very specific situation, I've been asked to group without this tool. A lead I've been given is to use "two selects" to do it.

The group by in normal situation would be `GROUP BY iva_percent, c.cust_no, year, quarter`

How can be achieved?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_calc_quarter (_trimestre_2 INT, _anio_2 INT) 
RETURNS TABLE (trimestre_2 INT , anio_2 INT , v_cust_no_2 CHARACTER(5), v_iva_percent_2 INT,
             v_amount_2 REAL)
AS $$
BEGIN                                                    
    RETURN QUERY SELECT                                                                 
        EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM i.last_update_date)::int AS quarter,                
        EXTRACT(year    FROM i.last_update_date)::int AS year,                   
        c.cust_no, round((i.iva_amount * 100 / net_amount)::numeric,0)::int       
        AS iva_percent, SUM(i.iva_amount) AS amount                          
    FROM erp.tb_customer c JOIN erp.tb_invoice i ON i.cust_no = c. cust_no   
    WHERE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM i.last_update_date) = _trimestre_2 AND           
          EXTRACT(year    FROM i.last_update_date) = _anio_2

    ORDER BY    c.cust_no, iva_percent, amount;
    RETURN QUERY;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the exact error message? Add as update to your question.

Comment: `RETURN QUERY` should be `RETURN QUERY;`

Comment: I initially put return table but it gave me an error " RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set, use RETURN NEXT or RETURN TABLE"

Comment: I have added ; to return query, but now It tells me "missing SQL statement at or near ";"

Comment: Sorry, I was not paying attention. Just get rid of `RETURN QUERY;`, you already have `RETURN QUERY SELECT ... ;`.

Comment: Don't say sorry, you are helping me :) I have created the function., thanks

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the code is returning a record, instead of a table. so instead of having 5 columns I have all data within brackets , one line per record. How is that possible?  I'm calling the function like --> SELECT fn_calc_quarter (2,2022)

Comment: It should be `SELECT * FROM fn_calc_quarter (2,2022)`.